# Splitform not updating textbox / label

Tags: ms-access

I have a splitform showing datasheet view at the bottom of a standard Form.

One of the features of the form is that it shows a message saying whether or not a patient needs a review based on the value of a tick box (chkNeedsReview).

When I move between records using the record navigators this label will appear and disappear correctly based on the value of the tick box.

However if you select a record in the split form / datasheet at the bottom, it does show the correct record, and updates the tick box, but the label either stays incorrectly or is hidden incorrectly despite me running some vba code to make sure it is displayed using the Form_Current event.

I tried changing it to an unbound textbox but the problem persists.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of label control, expression in textbox:

`=IIf([chkNeedsReview], "This needs review", Null)`

Use Conditional Formatting if you want to add emphasis like bold/italics/underscore and/or color.

No VBA needed.

Comment: I put that in as the control of a textbox and now it just says #Name?

Comment: Sorry I was being stupid, I had previously changed your expression correctly but applied it incorrectly, so when I went back to do it properly I forgot to rename the control chk_NeedsReview

Comment: Glad it helped.